# Probability reguarding the product of two numbers

Tags: probability, probability-theory

**Question :** The sum of two non-negative quantities is $2n$. Find the probability that  their product is at least $3/4^{th}$ of the maximum product of such pairs.

So obviously the maximum of the product $a \times b$ subject to $a+b=2n$ is $n^2$. So we have to find the probability that

$$a \times b \geq \frac{3n^2}{4}$$ 
$$a \times (n-a )\geq \frac{3n^2}{4}$$
$$a^2  -na +\frac{3n^2}{4} \leq 0$$
So from here I find that $a \in [\frac{n}{2}, \frac{3n}{2}]$.

Is that correct? and how do I proceed from here?

Comment: There are typos in steps 2 and 3.

Comment: Once the typos are corrected, the condition that $\frac12n\leqslant a\leqslant\frac32n$ should emerge. Since $a$ is (presumably) uniformly chosen in $[0,2n]$, the event you are interested in has limiting probability $\frac12$ when $n\to\infty$.

Comment: No need for the limit: you get exactly $\frac{1}{2}$ for every finite positive $n$, not even necessarily an integer.

Comment: @Aloysius Are $a$ and $b$ supposed to be integers?

Comment: @pre-kidney This is kind of the whole point: If $n$, $a$ and $b$ are restricted to be integers, the probability may not be exactly $\frac12$.

Comment: @Did  I guess there is no such restriction because we have been studying continuous random variables this week in class.

Comment: Allright. Beware though that the symbol $n$ rather points to integers and that there is no point to restrict the setting to integer values of $n$ if $a$ and $b$ are not restricted to being integers as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon=n-a$. Then $a=n-\epsilon$ and $b=n+\epsilon$, so $ab=n^2-\epsilon^2$. The condition $ab\geq \frac{3n^2}{4}$ becomes $\epsilon^2\leq \frac{n^2}{4}$ so $|\epsilon|\leq n/2$.

It follows that $a\in [n/2,3n/2]$. Assuming that $a$ and $b$ are uniformly random subject to the constraints, it follows that the probability is $\frac{1}{2}$.